# Unpack variant types before formatting / deduce return value in template

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I have a custom variant type and want to format its instances using printf - format strings. I found this related [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn913181.aspx) which describes the use of variadic templates for printf.

So, this VariantType can take one of different types,

```
typedef enum VariantValueType
{
  VariantValueTypeInt32 = 1,
  VariantValueTypeFloat = 2,
  VariantValueTypeString = 3,
  // ...
} MyVariantValueType;
```

and has a backing `union` to hold its actual value.

```
typedef union VariantValue
{
  long Int32;
  float Float32;
  const char* String;
  // ...
} MyVariantValue;
```

Now I wanted to extract the values of any given `VariantTypes` before calling `printf`

```
template <typename ... Args>
void my_printf(char const * const format, Args const & ... args) noexcept
{
  printf(format, Format(args, std::is_same<Args, VariantType>()) ...);
}
```

while still treating built-in types as they are usually just given to `printf` using tag dispatching:

```
template<typename T>
T Format(T value, std::false_type)
{
  return value;
}
```

and *trying* to unpack the variant

```
template<typename T>
T Format(T value, std::true_type)
{
  VariantType var = static_cast<VariantType>(value);

  switch (var.Type())
  {
    case VariantValueTypeInt32:
      return var.Value().Int32;
    case VariantValueTypeFloat:
      return var.Value().Float32;
    // ...
  }
}
```

This calls the copy-constructor of the `VariantType`- which results in unexpected outputs:

```
my_printf("%s, %+03d\n", VariantType("test"), VariantType(5));
```

for example prints "test, +00" instead of "test, +05".
I also tried to define the templates as

```
// Variant
template<typename T, typename U>
U Format(T value, std::true_type) {}

// Non-Variant
template<typename T, typename U>
U Format(T value, std::false_type) {}
```

which only seems to work for the actual Variant and can't deduce `U` for simple types.

Is there any way to unpack variants / deduce types more reliably?

Comment: You seem to nearly have a [mcve]. Can you finish it and post the full sample code plus tell us what "does not really work that well" means, as well as any compiler errors you may be getting?

Comment: @AndyG Thank you for your response, added the example.

Comment: You cannot return different type from Format according to variant content. You could do the other way: "convert" argument to a specific type according to format: `template<typename Out, typename In> Out To(In)`... `my_printf<const char*, int>("%s, %+03d\n", VariantType("test"), VariantType(5));`. Retrieving type from literal type would be tricky.

Comment: [boost format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/format/) might interest you.